# NodeJs with Mysql select IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm use NodeJs and MySql. I want to select data that IS NOT NULL. I try to find answer every where but no any answer or example. Can any one guide me or give me a link to find more information? 
This is my code

```js
app.get('/student', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?', ["IS NOT NULL"], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows (SYNTAX 1) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

You can do it as follows (SYNTAX 2) :

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (id <=> NULL);
```

Comment: I tried it with connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE NOT (id <=> NULL); it work find but it don't work when I use with escape   connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE NOT (id <=> ?); ' ["NULL"]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason why you can't just do:

```
app.get('/student', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id IS NOT NULL', [], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Unless you're parsing an SQL query that has a where clause based on user input, there is no need to use a prepared statement.

Prepared statements with question marks and an array of objects that replace those question marks should only be used for SQL queries that utilize user input.

Let's say you're asking the user to enter his student ID and student password and you will perform authentication. Then you should use something like:

```
app.get('/student', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?', [studentIdFromUser], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

instead of:

```
app.get('/student', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ' + studentIdFromUser.toString(), [], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Because, if the user enters `1;DROP TABLE student;` to the student ID field and presses enter, this is what happens:

1. In case #1, where you have the question mark and the array that contains `studentIdFromUser`, the query is parsed into something safe and nothing bad happens
2. In case #2, where you just append the student ID onto the SQL query, you drop your `student` table.

Comment: @ardilguez Yes I have to parsing an SQL query that has a where clause based on user input. That why I have to do prepare statement but some time I want to get data from every row. Can you  suggest any solution?

Comment: in your `is not null` case, you don't need to use a prepared statement, you can just use a plain text sql query. unless you're using a where clause that is based on a comparison to a user input, like my second example, you don't need to use a prepared statement. Also, `is not null` shouldn't be a user input.

Comment: If you want to get all the data, might as well go with `select * from students` without a where clause.